# Warning: Invalid value for prop `value` on <input> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm getting this warning and I can't find out why: "Invalid value for prop `value` on  tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM."

```
const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState({});
```

```
const sendPost = async () => {
    if (inputValues.link.length > 0) {
      setPostList([...postList, inputValues]);
      setInputValues('');
    } else {
      console.log('Empty inputs. Try again.');
    }
  };

  const onInputChange = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    setInputValues(values => ({...values, [name]: value}))
  };
```

```
const renderConnectedContainer = () => (
    <div className="connected-container">
      <form
      onSubmit={(event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        sendPost();
      }}
    >
      <input 
        type="text" 
        placeholder="Enter title!" 
        name="title" value={inputValues.title || ""} 
        onChange={onInputChange}/>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        placeholder="Enter link!" 
        name="link" 
        value={inputValues.link || ""} 
        onChange={onInputChange}/>
      <textarea 
        type="text-area" 
        placeholder="Enter description!" 
        name="description" 
        value={inputValues.description || ""} 
        onChange={onInputChange}/>
      <button type="submit" className="cta-button submit-post-button">Submit</button>
    </form>
   </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `sendPost` handler, you are resetting the `inputValues` state to an empty string `''` instead of back to the initial state of an empty object `{}`. `inputValues.title` is ok since it's just undefined, but `inputValues.link` (*i.e. `''.link`*) is actually a deprecated function.

[String.prototype.link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link)

> > **Deprecated**: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from
> > the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or
> > may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and
> > update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the
> > bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature
> > may cease to work at any time.
>
> The `link()` method creates a string representing the code for an
> `<a>` HTML element to be used as a hypertext link to another URL.

Just reset the `inputValues` back to the initial state.

```
const sendPost = async () => {
  if (inputValues.link.length > 0) {
    setPostList([...postList, inputValues]);
    setInputValues({});
  } else {
    console.log('Empty inputs. Try again.');
  }
};
```